# Android fragments switch best practices

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 step application^
1 step user choose what he need for example:
-Cars
-Buildings
...

2 step - After click on item need to show list of cars|buildings or something else;
3 step - show details of item

Example:
1 step - Cars -> 2 step - Mazda someModel -> 3 step - Details of model

And now..can you recommend me right way to this:
on smartphone all warking easly, one fragment will be replace to another
on tablet how to do:
1 step - 1 fragment - List of types - Cars|Buildings....

2 step - 2 fragment - List of types and list of items selected type

3 step - 2 fragment - List of items and details of item after select

I hope clearly explained what i want;

Some way which i know:
1 - Create horizontal linearlayout and add/replace/remove fragment
2 - Create layout which include 2 framelayout(for every fragment) and SHOW/HIDE second fragment
...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just have a FrameLayout in your activity and you replace the fragment in this FrameLayout for each step. You can even customize the animation.

Edit: For tablet, you can have a horizontal LinearLayout. If you want the left Fragment (the list of types or the list of items) to take 1/3 of the screen and the right fragment (list of items or details) to take 2/3 of the screen, you can use the weight property of the LinearLayout.

During step 1, your LinearLayout only contains a FrameLayout with a `weight` of 1. This on will be full screen.

When you will switch to step 2, you don't replace the fragment inside of the first container, you simply add programmatically a new FrameLayout container with a `weight` of 2. Both container will take the good amount of space you want.

To dynamically set the weight of a View, you have to edit its LayoutParams :

```
ViewGroup rightContainer = new FrameLayout(this);
rightContainer.setId(View.generateViewId()); // you need an ID to perform a fragment transaction
// api 17+ only, use static ID or copy/paste the code for lower platform
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2); // the last param is the weight
rightContainer.setLayoutParams(lp);
linearLayout.addView(rightContainer);
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
  .add(rightContainer.getId(), ItemListFragment.newInstance(), "ITEM_LIST")
  // add custom transition if needed
  .commit();
```

When you will switch to step 3, you just replace the fragment inside of the second container to show the detail and replace the fragment inside of the first container to show the list of items.

If you don't want to recreate the fragments and re-use old instances, you can retrieve a fragment by tag if you added it to the FragmentManager with a tag.

```
ItemListFragment oldFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("ITEM_LIST");
DetailFragment detailFragment = DetailFragment.newInstance();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
  .replace(leftContainer.getId(), oldFragment, "ITEM_LIST")
  .replace(rightContainer.getId(), detailFragment, "DETAIL")
  .commit();
```

Comment: Replace for smartphone , but for tablet I want to show 2 column

Comment: two questions:
1 - how to set wegith property programmaticaly
2 - last paragraph - fragment get data from net and i don't want to get data twice when

Comment: I just edited the answer to provide more code about your concerns.

Comment: I tried to replace like that:
....replace(containerId, this).commit();
:D
thanks )